# Scanning std::array, forwards vs backwards

Tags: c++, performance

I want to do a linear scan through an std::array as fast as possible. Should I scan forward (from index 0 to index n) or backward (from index n to index 0), or does it even matter?

Comment: If you think it could matter, you should be in a position to measure it in a realistic running scenario. That is the only way to know for sure.

Comment: The complexity is the same, but cache performance may influence the actual performance. I'd go for forward.

Comment: I disagree strongly with closing this as "primarily opinion-based". This is a Teachable Moment and I think we should take advantage of it to illustrate why the _real_ answer is to reconsider the question.

Answer (score 4):

Traditionally, the advice would be to scan n-to-zero, because comparison to zero in the loop control is cheaper in most architectures than comparison to other numbers. (As others have pointed out, prefetch caching may or may not negate that advantage, depending again on details of the architecture.)

Determining whether that actually makes a difference in your scenario -- and whether it's a difference that's significant given what you're doing in the loop body -- and whether the loop makes any difference at all in the performance of your application -- requires either a lot more analysis of your specific code and architecture, or some real-world testing.

**Standard reminder for people trying to micro-optimize:** Infinite performance improvement of something that accounts for 1% of your runtime takes infinite effort and yields 1% improvement. 10% improvement of something that accounts for 10% of your runtime takes a lot less effort and yields the same benefit. *Don't waste time micro-optimizing the wrong things.* Do proper performance analysis and let that guide you -- and remember that an algorithmic or data-structure change is likely to be more productive than tweaking a few instructions.

Comment: +1 for *"Standard reminder for people trying to micro-optimize"* Any current compiler is far better than humans on micro-optimizations

Comment: +1, though I fear for some readers, your first paragraph will be the only one that sinks in.

Comment: Hence the bold, to try to call attention to the final paragraph. But I wanted to start by trying to answer the question as asked, then expand into why it was probably the wrong question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't thought about the zero comparison could be faster, I was mainly concerned about the cache performance as you also mention, and if there were any heuristics on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

This depends heavily on actual scenario.

There are two main things to consider here.

First is loop overhead, backwards (`n` -> `0`) loop could technically be a little faster. But this would matter only if the loop is very tight, that is loop body is trivial enough and it's logic isn't substantially affected by the order.

The other thing is memory access, historically CPUs would be better at caching/prefetching forwards, but nowadays they do it pretty well both ways. Thing is, this isn't so simple because it would depend on actual access pattern and the CPU.

A very, *very* general answer could be: for loop with non-trivial body and big enough `n` there *should probably* be little to no difference.

But the actual answer is: it's complicated, if you suspect it has potential to make any substantial performance difference, the only way to tell is to test it.